# Do Google Channel API Bi-Directional Sockets Exist?

Tags: api, channel

In the docs for the Google Channel API it says:

"A channel is a one-way communication path through which the server sends updates to a specific JavaScript client identified by its Client ID."

In their diagrams they show a client sending its state with a POST.  This seems like it would be slow.  Can the client communicate with the Channel API through a socket?  Or must it send via POST?

Answer (score 1):

POST is a message type indicator and message format.

Major edit after more research!

See [Google API doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html)

Looks like messages from the browser to the server do indeed open new HTTP-level connections to send a POST message. Whether a new TCP/IP connection is needed or not depends on the browser's management of TCP connections--new browsers do a better job of this. See [wikipedia HTTP persistent connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)

Re: `This seems like it would be slow.` Usually the browser traffic is asymmetrical--with most of the data from the server to the browser. Comet will help that use case.

Re: `Can the client communicate with the Channel API through a socket?` Do you mean IP socket? Browsers don't have an api for that. Do you mean "[web socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_socket)?" I'm 98% sure it wouldn't work to combine the two techniques. But you could try...

Comment: Larry, thanks for looking at this.  The Channel API server connection is indeed a web socket connection:  "The JavaScript client opens a socket using the token provided by the server. It uses the socket to listen for updates on the channel."  It just seems peculiar that it is uni directional.  You listen on a socket, and send on a POST.